# Марьванна – сердце нашего коллектива. Стоит ли кавычить «сердце»?

Tags: кавычки, метафора

Марьванна – сердце нашего коллектива. Стоит ли кавычить «сердце»?

Answer (score 3):

> Стоит ли кавычить «сердце»?

Нет, в данном случае это общеупотребимое значение слова, которое зафиксировано в толковых словарях.

В словаре [Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5&all=x), например:

> **Сердце**
>   ...
>   6. чего. Центр, главная часть чего-л. *С. города.*

Answer (score 0):

Кавычить не стоит. Должен заметить, смысл метафоры мне не совсем ясен, но возможно, он раскрывается в другом предложении. Есть две возможности (в обоих случаях кавычки не ставятся).

1. Сердце как центр, главная часть коллектива. В таком смысле я бы не стал слово *сердце* употреблять, тут больше подходят неодушевленные предметы, например сердце города:

   > *Он расположен в самом сердце Сочи среди пышной зелени деревьев, благоухания южных цветов. [Елена Зенина. Морская симфония (2001)
2. Сравнение коллектива с организмом, а человека с его сердцем. Это лучше, но хорошо бы уточнить, что имеется в виду. Движение "крови" в коллективе? Тогда что имеется в виду под кровью колектива?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88626/discussion-on-answer-by----------).

Answer (score 0):

Общеупотребительную метафору не следует брать в кавычки, иначе у читателя могут возникнуть некие ненужные вопросы. А вот в целом аллегория «Марьванна — сердце и т. д.» (где слово *сердце* говорит об особой *глубине*, *глубинности*), без развития темы — либо крайне редкий случай в литературе, либо представляет яркую новацию: в НКРЯ таковой не нашлось. Но есть (и во множестве) другие, которые не вызывают сомнений:

> ― Вера, убежденность в том, что ты поступаешь правильно, что сердце и
>   душа твои чисты, в них только одно ― любовь и жалость к людям. [Л.
>   Кодзаева. Матушка // «Работница», 1989].
>
> ― В живописи главное, если хочешь знать, даже не рисунок, не линия, не
>   цвет и свет, а сердце и душа!!! [Юрий Азаров. Подозреваемый (2002)].
>
> — Эстремадура, как и Андалусия, Валенсия, Каталония, Арагон... ― это живое сердце и душа Испании. [И. Кудрин. Забытая
>   Эстремадура // «Вокруг света», 1984].
>
> — Всё наше сердце и душа ― Скобелевым и Суворовым, ― и никакого доверия
>   к начитанным в учебниках схоластам... [М. О. Меньшиков. Инвалидная психология
>   (1914.02.20).

Comment: По-моему, толко "сердце Испании" — метафора, все остальное — о человеческом сердце.

Comment: Ну если «чистое сердце» про человеческое сердце, то я умываю руки, человеческие.

Comment: Конечно про человеческое;  "сердце и душа твои чисты" — обращение к человеку, речь о его сердце. Может Вы хотели сказать, что это, мол, не то сердце, которое кровь гоняет, а что-то другое?  Так это вопрос, что называть сердцем и это не метафора.

Comment: Как представляется сердце решает контекст. Если рядышком — про душу, сердце  — не орган. Перечитал, — нормальные примеры; у последнего «всё наше» только немного странно выглядит: «все наши сердца и души» просится.

Comment: Да, странный оборот. Чувствуется влияние предыдущей фразы: "Все наше доверие героям!". Я бы предложил три варианта взамен: "всё сердце и душа каждого из нас", "всё сердце и душа нашего народа",  "все наши сердца и души". Последнее естественней, конечно.